# Extjs 4.2.1 - Draggable/Undraggable windows on the fly

Tags: window, draggable, extjs4.2, on-the-fly

In my application, I have 4 windows on the screen and all the windows are draggable.

My need is that, all the windows should be made draggable/undraggable on a click of a button(toggle).

I set draggable true/false on the fly. But, the property is not updated. I even closed and opened the window once the draggable property is changed. But, ended in vain.

Any help is appreciated.

I think, I need **doLayout()** kind of thing to update the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `enable` and `disable` methods on `window.dd` object:

```
w.dd.disable(); // disables d&d
w.dd.enable(); // enables d&d
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/cb7rtcya/1/ (It's written in Ext JS 5, but should work also on 4)